# Getting the latest files in a S3 Bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to fetch only files I haven't fetched previously from an S3 Bucket. I also need their file names so I know which files to handle in each iteration.

I've decided I don't want to implement a queue listener for now so using the notifications isn't what I want.

I've considered using the downloadBucket api and turning on "debug", and then parse the results to find the files that were downloaded.

Does anyone know a better way, or if turning on debug impacts performance?

I'm using laravel/php to implement this.

Comment: I think there isn't really a simple way to do this with S3 alone since S3 is only bare storage.

Comment: *"I've decided I don't want to implement a queue listener for now"* Considering that this is, in fact, the optimal solution... why not?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot a) I need to implement a listener - which is more code, which means more time spent. b) If I have two systems that need to do this to the same directory - which may be possilble with two queues, but this doesn't scale with my effort - which is expensive.

Comment: If you have multiple systems working the same directory, you send the notification to SNS, which fans it out to multiple SQS queues, one for each workflow.  Or, as I have done in one case like this for a bucket with multiple millions of objects, I have notifications that query and write S3 object metadata to a database table, which I can index to my heart's content, and query quickly and efficiently for keys, prefixes ("folders"), dates, versions, and even metadata, which is stored in its own normalized tables.

Answer (score 1):

S3 doesn't have a filter features in list_objects. So the best things you can do, is MOVE processed file to a new bucket or prefix. So you don't need to worry which key is "processed".

Thus you can do this (algorithm, not code)

```
- store new_key to new/ folder
  - select everything in new/ prefix
    - process each key
    - copy key to proceesed/ prefix 
    - delete key in new/ prefix
```

Note : Every 1000 PUT/COPY/POST/LIST will cost you a 0.005 cents. So use it sparingly .